# Pass data between fragments in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to pass some data from PowerofMind to wishlist fragment but I encountered with some error.

This Activity from where data has to be transferred

```
      wish?.setOnClickListener({
            val name = "Power of Subconcoius Mind"
            val intent = Intent(this@PowerofMind, WishlistFragment::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Book: ", name)
            startActivity(intent)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Added to WishList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```

I want to show data in this activity as

```
class WishlistFragment : Fragment() {
    var result: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wishlist, null)
        result =view.findViewById(R.id.list1)
        val name = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("Book: ")
        list1.text = "Book: $name"
        return view
    }
}
```

But there is an error on Intent. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to instantiate a fragment with factory method:

```
companion object {
    private const val MY_DATA_KEY = "my_data"
    private const val ANOTHER_DATA_KEY = "another_data"
    fun newInstance(mySerializableData: Any, anotherData: Int) = MyFragment().apply {
        //bundleOf() is an exstension method from KTX https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx
        arguments = bundleOf(MY_DATA_KEY to mySerializableData, ANOTHER_DATA_KEY to anotherData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the codes I edited in the question itself. Also there is an error to declare the wishlist fragment in Android Manifest File. is there any solutionn?Thanks for the help

Comment: @LeninBakhara seems like your WishlistFragment is not a fragment, by your code it looks like is an activity, please check which class WishlistFragment extends, I am sure is an Activity

Comment: Sir, Its a fragment I made in navigation drawer as wishlist

Comment: Then the fragments must been instantiated not like activities. Just replace your startActivity(intent) with corresponding logic, for example with getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replaceFragment(containerResId, fragmentInstance).commit()

Comment: fragmentInstance can be obtained through factory method defined by you like in my answer, an example MyFragment.newInstance(myData, anotherData)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can pass data between fragment in kotlin using Parcelable class:

on Button Click:

```
     override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        firstName = editTextName!!.text.toString()
        lastName = editTextLast!!.text.toString()
        Toast.makeText(context, firstName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//        val viewFragment = ViewFragment()
//        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, viewFragment)
//        transaction.commit()

        var details = Details(firstName!!, lastName!!)
        val viewFragment = ViewFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(KEY_PARSE_DATA, details)
        viewFragment.setArguments(bundle)
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, viewFragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
```

Here is an parcel class how to handle data

```
     @Parcelize
class Details(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : Parcelable
```

on another fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false)

        textViewName = view.findViewById(R.id.text_name_another) as TextView
        textViewLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.text_surname_another) as TextView

        val bundle = arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            val details = bundle.getParcelable<Details>(KEY_PARSE_DATA)
            textViewName!!.setText(details.firstName)
            textViewLastName!!.setText(details.lastName)
        }


        return view
    }
```

Currently I don't know if this required or not in kotlin in app gradle (Check this before used)

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your WishlistFragment you are creating a new Intent instead of getting the one provided by the activity.

As you are using Kotlin, you can directly use intent instead of getIntent().
You could use also the synthetic advantage of kotlin, and drop that findViewById.

And as a tip, do not use string concatenation ;)

Your fragment would look something like the following:

```
class WishlistFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wishlist, null)
    val name = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("Book: ")
    many.text = "Book: $name"
}
```